# Return to the last activity (PreferenceManager)

Tags: android, android-activity, return, sharedpreferences

I would like to return to the last activity, the user has closed before closing down the application. I have implemented this method to communicate the 3 activities, but in my code there is something wrong. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

MenuActivity (opens when the app is launched)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String lastActivity = ((Intent) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)).getStringExtra("sent");

         if (lastActivity != null && lastActivity.equals("activity_2")){
                        {
                             Intent myIntentActivity1 = new Intent(menu.this,activity_2.class);
                               startActivity(myIntentActivity1);
                               }

                        } 

         if (lastActivity != null && lastActivity.equals("activity_3")){
                            {
                                 Intent myIntentActivity2 = new Intent(menu.this,activity_3.class);
                                   startActivity(myIntentActivity2);
                                   }

                            }

                            else {
                            Intent myIntentActivity3 = new Intent(menu.this,menu.class);
                               startActivity(myIntentActivity3);


                        }
```

Activity 2

//some code

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
     Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        ((Intent) e).putExtra("sent", "activity_2");
        e.commit();
}
```

Activity 3

//some code

```
@Override
    public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
     Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        ((Intent) e).putExtra("sent", "activity_3");
        e.commit();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without defining what "something wrong" means, I'm going to venture a guess.

Have a look at the following code snippet:

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
((Intent) e).putExtra("sent", "activity_2");
e.commit();
```

You're casting an `Editor` to an `Intent`. That makes little sense, because there is no relationship between the two classes. As such, you're probably seeing a `ClassCastException` somewhere.

In stead, you should get rid of the cast and use the correct method provided by the `Editor` class to save a string:

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
e.putString("sent", "activity_2");
e.commit();
```

That's half of the problem. A similar one exists when you read the value back from the preferences:

```
String lastActivity = ((Intent) PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)).getStringExtra("sent");
```

You're trying to cast a `String` to an `Intent`. Again, this will give you the aforementioned exception. Get rid of the cast and use the correct method to retrieve the string.

```
String lastActivity = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("sent", null);
```

---

Edit: You can potentially make the logic a little smarter, allowing you to get rid of the if-else construction. This could be especially beneficial if you're planning on adding more activities later on.

The idea is to store the class name of the activity, which you can then leverage to construct the right intent. Something like this (untested):

Save:

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
e.putString("sent", getClass().getName());
e.commit();
```

Restore:

```
String lastActivity = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("sent", null);
if (lastActivity != null) {
    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(lastActivity);
    Intent myIntentActivity = new Intent(menu.this, cls);
    startActivity(myIntentActivity);
}
```

Probably requires a little bit of tweaking to avoid potential cycles where one activity recursively launches itself, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: does not work I have left blank page as if it repeats the same action to return to the menu (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Do each of your activities handle the 'back' button by finishing the activity?  You should consider moving to Fragment based activities instead of multiple activities like this.  Your main FragmentActivity could then manage which was the active Fragment when exited (via the saved instance Bundle and/or SharedPreference similar to what you are doing now.)